# show comments with topic post, post, image

Tags: php, mysql

Okay i'm trying to display images with replies its linked to. I found this code but the results are empty with only the column title names coming up. Does anyone know why.

```
 <?php

   include 'connect.php';





        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `mid`";
        $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($res2) == 0){
            echo "There are no topics in this forum, <a  href=\"./index.php?act=create&     id=".$row['id']."\">click here</a> to create a topic!\n";
        }else {
            echo "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"3\" cellpadding=\"3\" width=\"100%\">\n";
            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"4\" align=\"right\"><a  href=\"./index.php?act=create&id=".$row['mid']."\">create a topic</a></td></tr>\n";
            echo "<tr align=\"center\"><td class=\"forum_header\">Title</td><td class=\"forum_header\">User</td><td class=\"forum_header\">Date Created</td><td class=\"forum_header\">Replies</td></tr>\n";
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
                $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `reply` WHERE `mid`";
                $res3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
                $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res3);
                echo "<tr align=\"center\"><td><a href=\"./index.php?act=topic&id=".$row2['mid']."\">".s($row2['name'])."</a></td><td>".uid($row2['who'])."</td><td>".$row2['date']."</td><td>".$row3[reply']."</td></tr>\n";
            }
            echo "</table>\n";
        }

    }
}

 ?>
```

Name is the name of the image or path in mysql.

Table structure

```
TABLE Header
username
 id
who
 where

Table images
message
 name
mid  - id that auto increments when image is loaded
id
content

Table reply
 mid  id that is taken from images mid to relate image to reply.
reply
id ----this is only for an id for a reply that is auto increment
```

CODE DOES NOT WORK. Sorry but geez no answer.

Comment: It's unfinished. It's supposed to look along the lines of `SELECT * FROM images WHERE mid='some_ID'`

Comment: no that didn't change anything.

Comment: Well of course it didn't change anything, you need to do the rest of the work. That was just an example.

Comment: anyway the reason it isn't showing seems to be because the coding is wrong though the msyql is right the echo html and fetch associate seems to wrong.

Answer (score 0):

okay. I'm really disappointed that a lot of people could not get this simple answer. The answer is simple.

```
    SELECT images.name, GROUP_CONCAT(  'reply.reply'
  SEPARATOR  "|" ) 
  FROM images, reply
  WHERE reply.mid = images.mid
  OR reply.mid = reply.reply
   GROUP BY images.mid
```

Since I'm a nice person i leave this answer for people who will get stuck on such a simple problem. Thank me.

Answer (score -1):

Your Sql Query is wrong :-

```
  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `mid`";
                                   ^
  $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `reply` WHERE `mid`";
                                   ^
```

Correct your Where condition everything should work..

Comment: no the echo html and the rest of the code is wrong except the mysql queries.

Comment: the answer is up. The code above is wrong. Try to input only the msyql query below.